# Time delay in papers peer-review process

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission, editors, elsevier, invited-paper

I submitted a paper to a high impact Elsevier journal. However, the problem is things going very slowly. In fact the first reviewer submitted his comments after 30 days exactly which is today but the other one didn't bother at all to accept or decline the invitation.

I'm a reviewer myself and I know sometimes you get busy but this behavior of not declining annoys me so much. If you are busy, just decline and not leave the invitation without respond for over 30 days. What do you suggest? Should I contact the editor and encourage him to take the process himself since it requires 2 reviewers to take decision, or should I suggest other reviewers which may/may not respond to the invitation & take another 30 days or more to respond.

It's been more than 8 weeks since the initial submission and going this way the research loses its novelty since others will implement what I found. So any suggestions?

Comment: This seems mostly to be a frustrated rant more than anything else.

Comment: @Jon Cluster kind of..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can be frustrating, but often the review process can take substantially longer than 8 weeks.  I would say there is nothing unusual about your case so far.

You could send a brief, polite email to the editor enquiring on the progress of the review.

Avoid anything that sounds like you are trying to tell the editor how to do his job, though.

Comment: Well i send him an email already thats how i got  the infos above about one reviewer accepted and submitted a respond today and the other not even responding to the invitation by accepting or declining  and that piss me off...but why the editor didn't find invite another one (i know its difficult) +30 days without accepting or declining the invitation really show some lack of respect...but im thinking of emailing him again to speed things up but any idea?

Comment: @aminevsaziz nagging the editor won't accomplish anything other than giving you a bad reputation with him.  I don't think there is anything you can do other than email occasionally to politely check progress (I would not email more than once a month).  Your only other option is to eventually withdraw the paper and submit it somewhere else if you are unhappy the delays.

Comment: Keep in mind that the editor is doing you a favour, he's not working for you.